# ubuntu 13.04 and g++

Tags: linux, ubuntu, g++

I had recently installed ubuntu 13.04 and I'm a new linux user but I am unable to compile g++ code.

It says

```
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

When I tried to install `g++` using following statements

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

It says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8 (= 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~13.04) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libcloog-isl4 (>= 0.17) but it is not installable
           Depends: libisl10 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: try `sudo aptitude update`; `sudo aptitude upgrade`; `sudo aptitude install build-essentials g++-4.8` ; BTW your question is not related to source code so is off topic on stack overflow

Comment: What makes you think you need another repo?  Do you need version 4.8? Ubuntu 13.04 has `g++-4.7` which should be "good enough" for most things. The older versions 4.4, 4.5 and 4.6 are also available.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch small typo, it's actually `build-essential` << singular, not plural :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch and ubuntu does not have 4.8 in the main repos; Debian does though.

Comment: its not working for me :( sudo: aptitude: command not found

Comment: @sarashahid so you don't have `aptitude`, you can use any of the `apt-get` commands posted below. or `apt-get install aptitude` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu, the easiest way to get all the build tools including `g++` is to

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

I suggest you check [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) for more info.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate

Comment: @sarashahid please edit your question with any new info (so it's easier to read)

Comment: Can you check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure the `main` ubuntu repo is present and not commented out? `build-essential` is a core package. also try `apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

You just do try "sudo apt-get install g++" in the command line?
so package manager will try to install missing package. Do not request specific version and You will be fine! It fails just because of specific version requirement.